# Get Page Number of PDF document Page number start with 1

Tags: java

I'm getting a pdf page number using itext jar for a pdf document which page number starts with 1 and goes to x. Using the below code returns null if the page number starts with 1 (pdf conaints more than one page).  But it returns the page number if I change the page number of the document (eg., 2 - x ).

```
String pdfFileName = "test.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileName);
String[] labels1 = PdfPageLabels.getPageLabels(reader);
System.out.println("labels " + labels1);
   if(labels1 != null)
   { System.out.println(" labels.length " + labels1.length);
       for (int i = 0; i < labels1.length; i++){ 
           System.out.println(labels1[i]);
       } 
   }
```

How can I get the pagelabel of pdf document which page numbers start 1. Any reason behind on that? or need to do any changes in the document?

Comment: 'using the below code'. Okeeeeey. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry... Here is the code...                                                                  String pdfFileName = "test.pdf";
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileName);     
 String[] labels1 = PdfPageLabels.getPageLabels(reader);
   
  System.out.println("labels " + labels1);
  if(labels1 != null)
  {
   System.out.println(" labels.length " + labels1.length);
   for (int i = 0; i < labels1.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(labels1[i]);
      }
  }

Comment: What is the issue on getting page number of pdf which starts page number 1?? Pls guide me anyone....